# Return random Element from a Swift 3 `CountableRange`

Tags: swift, swift3

I want:

```
let randomNumber = (1...10).sample
```

Specifically I only need this for Integers, but it would fun to know a general solution.

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate of that question, though one of the provided answers to that question does coincidentally answer this question specifically for integers… but NOT for a general solution. So congratulations moderators, as usual you make me feel that StackOverflow is no longer a good place to ask questions. Instead you are closing valid questions for some ridiculous goal of "cleanliness” that you also in fact are not achieving.